# AngularJS - Possibility of having automatic typing fields when clicking modal

Tags: angularjs

I've been googling for the possibility of this but haven't found anything, perhaps I have googled the wrong thing but I generally can't find it, therefore, I am wondering is it possible for this to be done at all.

[image]

Attempting to make it user-friendly, is possible when you click to enter a value in a modal view. Instead of having to click on the text box, is it possible to have it automatically start typing when it pops up instead of having to click on it?

AngularJS:

```
app.controller('UserGroupCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $compile, $uibModal, $log, SpringDataRestService, NgTableParams) {

    $scope.refreshUserGroups = function () {
        SpringDataRestService.query(
            {
                "collection": "userGroupsInternal",
                "method": "flattened"
            },
            function (response) {                   // Success Function
                $scope.userGroupTableOptions = new NgTableParams({
                    sorting: {
                        siteName: "desc",
                    }
                }, {
                    dataset: response,
                    counts: [],
                });
            },
            function (response) {
                clearDentAlerts($scope.alerts);
                reportDentAlert($scope.alerts, new DentAlert(AlertType.ERROR, generateAlertMessage(response)));
            }
        );
    };

    $scope.refreshUserGroups();

    $scope.openModal = function (group) {
        var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            windowClass: "",
            templateUrl: "views/modals/user-groups.html",
            controller: 'ModalUserGroupEditCtrl',
            size: null,
            resolve: {
                group: function () {
                    return group;
                },
                SpringDataRestService: function () {
                    return SpringDataRestService;
                },
                onComplete: function () {
                    return $scope.refreshUserGroups;
                },
                groupType: function () {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
    };
});

app.controller('ModalUserGroupEditCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http, $log, SpringDataRestService, group, groupType, onComplete) {
    $scope.onComplete = onComplete;
    $scope.alerts = [];
    if (group) {
        SpringDataRestService.get(
            {
                "resource": "userGroupsInternal",
                "id": group.id
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: response._links.groupType.href
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                    $scope.targetEntity.groupType = response.data.id;
                });
                $scope.targetEntity = response;
            }
        );
        $scope.isNew = false;
    } else {
        $scope.isNew = true;
        $scope.targetEntity = {};
        if (groupType) {
            $scope.isGroupProvided = true;
            $scope.targetEntity.groupType = groupType.id;
        }
    }

    // Get list of group type for pulldown menu
    $scope.idList = [];
    SpringDataRestService.get(
        {"collection": "userGroupTypes"},
        function (response) {                   // Success Function
            var userGroupTypes = response._embedded.userGroupTypes;
            for (var i = 0, len = userGroupTypes.length; i < len; i++) {
                var newUserGroup = {id: userGroupTypes[i].id, name: userGroupTypes[i].name};
                $scope.idList.push(newUserGroup);
            }
        },
        function (response) {                   // Failure Function
            $scope.alerts.push(new DentAlert(AlertType.ERROR, generateAlertMessage(response)));
        }
    );

    // Handle cancel button event
    $scope.handleCancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.handleCreate = function () {
        if ($scope.targetEntity.groupType) {
            $scope.targetEntity.groupType = getResourceUri("userGroupTypes", $scope.targetEntity.groupType);
        } else {
            $scope.targetEntity.groupType = null;
        }
        SpringDataRestService.save(
            {"collection": "userGroupsInternal"},
            $scope.targetEntity,
            function (response) {                   // Success Function
                $scope.onComplete($scope.targetEntity);
                $uibModalInstance.close($scope.targetEntity);
            },
            function (response) {
                clearDentAlerts($scope.alerts);
                reportDentAlert($scope.alerts, new DentAlert(AlertType.ERROR, generateAlertMessage(response)));
            }
        );
    };

    $scope.handleUpdate = function () {
        if ($scope.targetEntity.groupType) {
            $scope.targetEntity.groupType = getResourceUri("userGroupTypes", $scope.targetEntity.groupType);
        } else {
            $scope.targetEntity.groupType = null;
        }
        SpringDataRestService.update(
            {
                "collection": "userGroupsInternal",
                "id": $scope.targetEntity.id
            },
            $scope.targetEntity,
            function (response) {                   // Success Function
                $scope.onComplete($scope.targetEntity);
                $uibModalInstance.close($scope.targetEntity);
            },
            function (response) {
                clearDentAlerts($scope.alerts);
                reportDentAlert($scope.alerts, new DentAlert(AlertType.ERROR, generateAlertMessage(response)));
            }
        );
    };

    $scope.handleDelete = function () {
        SpringDataRestService.delete(
            {
                "resource": "userGroupsInternal",
                "id": $scope.targetEntity.id
            },
            function (response) {                   // Success Function
                $scope.onComplete($scope.targetEntity);
                $uibModalInstance.close($scope.targetEntity);
            },
            function (response) {                   // Failure Function
                clearDentAlerts($scope.alerts);
                reportDentAlert($scope.alerts, new DentAlert(AlertType.ERROR, generateAlertMessage(response)));
            }
        );
    };

});
```

Comment: *"Automatic typing"*?? Do you mean autocomplete suggestions as you type?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using angularjs, you can write something like this in your controller, when your popup code is called.

```
var name = $window.document.getElementById('name');
name.focus();
```

Comment: Hey, sorry pretty new to angularjs. I've updated my code with angularjs now, where can I put that in and how?

Comment: you can put that line inside "ModalUserGroupEditCtrl" controller. and you need to pass $window in that controllers parameter